# FS105 v3 5-port switch - No IP Address/Connection

Tags: switch

Here's my current home + network setup.

I have an XFinity cable modem going into a Linksys router (let's call this family room router). That router is wired to another router directly (let's call this office router), both providing internet for both Wi-Fi and LAN connections. From the office router I have a LAN connection going into the office wall port which is part of the home wired network. When I go upstairs to the network switch board and plug in the office wall's ethernet cable directly to my laptop I get a internet connection immediately with correct DHCP and everything.

At this point once I found the wire I figured I would just plug that into a switch, and this way I can plug all the other upstairs room cables into that swtich and poof, internet for all wired wall ports upstairs.

When I attempted this with an FS105 v3 5-port switch by plugging both the ethernet coming from the office wall port and all the upstairs room cables also into the switch the laptop cannot get internet. On Windows 10 the ethernet adapter troubleshooter says "ip address configuration issue". I even tried using a static IP address and inputting the gateway/subnet settings manually. Still, no luck. Again, it works fine if the office wall port cable is plugged in directly, but when used in conjunction with the switch there is no internet.

I've tried all combinations of switch ports, and surprisingly enough when the office wall port cable is plugged into switch it will blink for activity about once every 5 seconds...and not consistently as the other cables going to all the upstairs rooms do which makes me think that is the issue (however I am stumped on how to fix that).

Any ideas on what I can try or should do to try to remedy this situation? Is a new switch or perhaps a confuguration missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: *"I've tried all combinations of switch ports"* - The wall cable goes into port 5. Also, cable lengths could (potentially) be an issue. Anything over 328 feet (100 meters) between devices  could be a problem.

Comment: Thanks, I think I actually might have come across new info. The color wiring on the two cables in the upstairs box are different...I'm thinking the upstairs bedrooms for some reason were just PoE cables, not wired for ethernet. That would also cause the issue.